# 2 issues about ASP.NET MVC,LINQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, webforms

1. Describe the Advantage and Disadvantage of ASP.NET MVC in comparison with ASP.NET Web form.
2. Depend on your choice to implement a new design or develop and compare source code or just explain the concept idea, the tasks of LINQ to SQL class that using as ORM, make comparison with NHibernate on the concept of developing the Data Access Layer for the application.

Comment: Try to go through the stackoverflow for possible duplicates/answers before you post any questions.

Comment: Is this a job interview?

Comment: Avoid linq to sql where linq to entities can be used

Answer (score 0):

MVC is a popular standard. I recommend using ASP.MVC than Webforms because it has all the advantages of MVC Architecture. and you can use many view engines such as Razor and NDjango.

For ORM you should use **Entity Framework**. It's really a wonderful framework.

The advantages of New Products such as ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework is that *THE OLD PRODUCTS SUCKS* and the disadvantage is the you need to *LEARN AGAIN*.